# Kendo numeric text box min max values not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo numeric text box in a directive. Even though I have set the min and max fields user is able to enter values beyond the range. This is the template string:

```
public template: string = '<input name = "numberField" type="text" id="searchIntNumberBox{{hashkey}}" required="required" ng-model="number" kendo-numeric-text-box k-options="options"' +
                               'min="{{minimumValue}}" max="{{maximumValue}}" maxlength = "{{maximumLength}}" step="5" style="width: 100%;height:26px"" />';
```

This is the options

```
$scope.options = {
            decimals: 0,
            format: '#',
            spin: (e) => {
                const value = e.sender.value();
                $scope.number = value;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
        };
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong. The min value is 0 and max value is 2147483647 but I can enter negative values and also values above the max value.

Comment: Can you create working demo for your issue?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/min) and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using kendo settings in the html format you need to add "k-":

```
 public template: string = '<input name = "numberField" type="text" id="searchIntNumberBox{{hashkey}}" required="required" ng-model="number" kendo-numeric-text-box k-options="options" k-min="minimumValue" k-max="maximumValue" maxlength = "{{maximumLength}}" step="5" style="width: 100%;height:26px"" />';
```

**Or in Controller:**

```
$scope.options = {
            decimals: 0,
            format: '#',
            spin: (e) => {
                const value = e.sender.value();
                $scope.number = value;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            min:yourMinValue,
            max:yourMaxValue
        };
```